# ActiveRecord drop down filter displaying all possibilities, not actually filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an index page that displays all objects regardless of category and region. At the top of that page is a drop down menu for filtering the objects - one drop down for category and one for region.

The items I am filtering are trips. There is a Trip model and trip controller. I also have a Region model and Category model, both of which `has_and_belongs_to_many :trips`.

In my trip controller I've created a trip query and assigned it to an instance variable @trips. And if certain conditions apply, ie. drop downs have been selected and params sent, then I join table(s) to the original Trip query that loads all of them.

Looks like this:

```
def all
  @trips = Trip.where(active: true,site: 'desktop').order(:trip_number).page(params[:page])
  @trips = @road_trips.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: params[:category][:id]}) if params[:category] && params[:category][:id] && !params[:category][:id].blank?
  @trips.joins(:regions).where(regions: {id: params[:region][:id]}) if params[:region] && params[:region][:id] && !params[:region][:id].blank?
end
```

I can successfully filter by only category and by category + region. But when I select only a region it displays all of the trips.

I thought the

```
!params[:category][:id].blank?
```

would solve this by ignoring the middle query and only joining the regions table, but its not.

Comment: Where is @road_trips defined?  Hard to tell by just looking at this, because although it's messy, it looks like it should work.  You need to look at your params from the log and the query that is getting executed to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `@trips = @trips.joins...` on the last line